# Why is my content moving down on the page?

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

I am using Dreamweaver to create an assignment for class. I saved my CSS file, go back to my home page and the main content of my page is pulled down but my footer leaving the "content" div empty and unable to my used. Could be a basic question but I'm unsure where my error is.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body {
 background-color: #D3D3D3; 
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px; 
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:link {
  color:#39c;
  outline: none;
}
a:visited {
  color:#39c;
  outline: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #000080;
  outline: none;
}
a:active {
  outline: none;
  -moz-user-focus: none;
}

h1 {
  font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size:28px;
  font-weight:700;
  color: #333;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;  
}

p {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 text-align: left;
}

ul {
 list-style-type: none; 
}

.wrapper {
 width: 1020px;
 min-height: 800px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 background-image: url(images/bg_wrapper.jpg);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-color: #fbf3f3;
}

#header {
 width: 1020px;
 height: 241px;
 background-image:url(images/logo.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 align: center; 
}

#nav {
 font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
 width: 1020px; 
 height: 75px; 
 background-color: #B8110B;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto; 
}
#nav li {
 display: inline-block;
 list-style-type: none;
}
#nav ul {
 padding: 10px;
}
#nav ul li a {
 font-family: Constantia, "Lucida Bright", "DejaVu Serif", Georgia, serif;
 color: #F4E9E9;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #B8110B;
 padding-top: 3px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 3px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 display: inline-block;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
 display: block;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: #c6403b;
 border: medium solid #87031B;
}


#container {
 width: 1020px;
 height: 800px; 
 align: center; 
}

#footer {
 width: 1020px;
 min-height: 100px;
 background-color: #0b3162;
}

#sidebar {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 10px; 
 margin-top: 20px; 
 width: 250px;
 height: 405px; 
  
}
#sidebar1 {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 10px; 
 margin-top: 20px; 
 width: 250px;
 height: 405px; 
  
}
#middle {
 overflow: hidden; 
 text-align: center; 
}

#content {
 margin-left: 10px; 
 background-color: white; 
 width: 1020px;
 height: 800px;
 align: center; 
}

.sidebartextleft {
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: ##000000;
 line-height: 2em;
}

.navtext {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-align: center;  
 padding-top: 5px; 
 padding-bottom: 50px; 
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #600;
 line-height: 1em;
}
.txtmain {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.txtsub {
  text-align: center;
  font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #CCC;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both; 
}
.wrapper #header .imgleft {
 text-align: right;

}
.h1header {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #03C;
 margin-top: 5px;
 text-align: center;
}
.h1sidebar {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #af1216;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: 5px;
 text-align: left; 
}
.h1sidebarleft {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #a9a9a9;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: 15px; 
 text-align: left; 
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TAKE IN LONDON</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <p><img name="Londonlogo" src="images/Londonlogo.jpg" width="1020" height="241" alt="TAKE IN LONDON logo"></p>
  </div>
  <div id="nav">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="activites.html">Things To Do </a></li>
      <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul></div>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="content">
         <p class="txtmain"><img name="LondonNight" src="images/LondonSkyline.jpg" width="995" height="300" alt="London Skyline At Night"></p>
        <div class="h1header"> Welcome to TAKE IN LONDON Travel Agency</div>
         .       </div>
          <div id="sidebar">
         <ul>
             <li class="navlinks"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li class="navlinks"><a href="location.html">LOCATION</a></li>
                <li class="navlinks"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
           <div id="middle"></div>
    
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
     <p class="txtmain">Founded in </p>
     </div>
         </div>
         </div>
         
             <div id="footer">
<p class="txtsub"> Copyright &copy; 2015, TAKE IN LONDON Travel | All rights reserved.</p>
    </div>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

please help me

Comment: Please post your code in your question.

Comment: Create your Demo [here](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Comment: as far as I can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/9ste8yog/, it's your header image that pushing the page down.

Comment: @Adelphia how do I go about fixing it? All my tags are closed

Comment: well, you could remove the image, or resize it, assuming that's the problem you're referring to.

Comment: Also, sometimes whitespace between the html markup can cause unwanted whitespace in the browser. I had a project once where i have to comment off all the whitespace in between the elements to get it to work properly. like this... `<someelement><!--      --><someotherelement>`

Comment: @Adelphia I resized the image in hopes that I would put the content back into my content div, with no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: Oh yeah, I've got tons of ideas, but I'm still not 100% clear on what the issue is. Maybe a link to the live page or perhaps a screenshot with some annotations would help.

Comment: @Adelphia I resized the image and it worked it looks like. I'm able to refill that content div. Thank you

Comment: You have an extra closing div on the end; right after `<div id="footer"></div>`. And you might want to use an actual IDE like `PHPStorm`, `WebStorm`, etc (sorry DreamWeaver, you simply suck at this.)

Answer (score 0):

Please please **don't use Dreamweaver**. It's put `div` elements in places they shouldn't be and its affecting the layout of your webpage.

You'll need to restructure the layout of your code to fix the issue.

A couple of pointers:

**1)** Are you aware that the content that the text "It founded" is written in your sidebar, not your main content div.

**2)** You give a fixed width to your `#container` div (`1020px`) and then within it you create two new div elements, `#content` and `#sidebar`. This is fine except that you then give the inner `#content` div a width of `1020px`. This means that the `#sidebar` div will always be placed under `#content`, not alongside it.

To correct this, reduce the `#content` width so that its width plus the width of `#sidebar` (plus any CSS margins) is less than 1020px.

I've created an example with these issue corrected however, you'll see that there are still underlying issues relating to the `div` structure. I've given the `#content`div a pink background and the `#sidebar` a green background so you can see their layout easier:

http://jsfiddle.net/kvsL0wwg/

If you're using Dreamweaver, use the code view and manually rearrange the structure to correct the layout.

My advice is to keep it simple, all HTML is is a bunch of nested elements (`head`, `body`, `div`, `p` etc...). Just start out by writing a really basic HTML page and add to it/style it slowly.